# Latin squares- completable-induction step

Tags: combinatorics, latin-square

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Partial latin square with $\le n-1$ filled cells](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169334/partial-latin-square-with-le-n-1-filled-cells)

http://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/22/ocr-ajc-v22-p247.pdf

Could someone please further explain the inductive step here in Theorem 5 in more explicit terms, or write the proof in explicit terms? I'm afraid I don't see how the inductive step makes sense for the completion of a Latin square.

Comment: Already asked at [Partial latin square with $\le n-1$ filled cells](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169334/partial-latin-square-with-le-n-1-filled-cells)

Comment: Gerry, I think it is worth mentioning that this is a corollary of the question you linked. Not a duplicate.

Comment: Danielle added this question to the original question - it is there.

Comment: And I’ve posted an answer there.